# How to find distinct values in an STL container C++11

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, containers

I might be too tired right now. How can you find the distinct values in a container, or range?

I've looked through the algorithms library but I can't see anything standard. I could've sworn there was a standard algorithm to do it.

Aside from having a container B which I only add elements from container A which don't already appear...

**EDIT: would be good to get a count of each too.... like... SQL in C++11

Comment: [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) may be?

Comment: What do you mean by "find" the elements? Do you want a container of iterators to those elements? Also, you probably mean "standard library container". I don't think the STL and C++11 go well together.

Comment: [`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) or [`std::unique_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy)?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I didn't mean STL, I just still think of them in turns on STL.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Those only remove consecutive duplicates.

Comment: Oh duh, I'll sort it first.

Comment: So long as you're sorting, you might as well just create a `set` and get sorted order along with removing duplicates. (And you can check the return value of `insert` to see whether the item is a duplicate.)

Answer (score 3):

Given an input vector `v`, you can do something like

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));              // O(N log N) where N = v.size()
auto it = std::unique(begin(v), end(v));  // O(N)
```

Equivalently (well not really, since you need extra memory, the above method is in-place), you can copy them into and out of a `std::set`:

```
std::set<T> s(begin(v), end(v));                 // O(N log N);
auto it = std::copy(begin(s), end(s), begin(v)); // O(N);
```

Note that in both cases you need to actually erase the removed elements

```
v.erase(it, end(v)); // O(K), where K is the number of removed duplicates
```